# hvplot.heatmap with pandas dataframe: How to specify value dimensions?

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh, holoviews, hvplot

I have a simple dataframe with columns and rows that I want to visualize using hvpolot.heatmap.
I can do something pretty similar with:

```py
df.style.background_gradient(cmap='summer')
```

.. in Jupyter, looks like:
[image]

The dataframe is pretty simple:

```py
> df.index
Index(['ackerland', 'friedhof', 'gartenland', 'gehoelz', 'golfplatz',
       'gruenland', 'heide', 'kleingarten', 'laubholz', 'mischholz', 'moor',
       'nadelholz'],
      dtype='object')
> df.columns
Index(['hiking', 'biking', 'walking', 'sport', 'friends', 'family', 'picnic'], dtype='object')
```

But when I do:

````py
>import hvplot.pandas
>df.hvplot.heatmap(colorbar=True)
ValueError: Dimensions must be defined as a tuple, string, dictionary or Dimension instance, found a NoneType type.```
````

This does also not work:

```py
>df.hvplot.heatmap(x=df.index, y=df.columns, colorbar=True)
ValueError: The truth value of a Index is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I've read most docs regarding this, but still don't fully understand how to specify value dimensions for pandas dataframe in hvplot/holoviews/bokeh:

- [Bokeh Heatmap Doc](http://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/HeatMap.html)
- [Pandas Dataframe Plot Doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)
- [hvplot plot doc](https://hvplot.pyviz.org/user_guide/Plotting.html)
- [hvplot intro with pd.df](https://hvplot.pyviz.org/user_guide/Introduction.html)
- [oloviews heatmap doc](http://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/HeatMap.html)

[edit] Added [feature request](https://github.com/pyviz/hvplot/issues/188)

Comment: I even found out how to plot this in holoviews: `hv.HeatMap({'x': df.columns, 'y':df.index, 'z': df}, ['x', 'y'], 'z')` but the same syntax does not work in hvplot

Comment: Thanks Alex, could you file an issue to ask us to support this in hvplot?

Comment: Thanks philippjfr! Sure, I'll report it asap (also, sorry for asking twice - you already explained to me once how to specify value dimensions, I am embarrassing aware of this)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**1) If your data is in the wide format that you have, with categories as index, and columns as values, like this:**

```
+--------------------------+
|         colA  colB  colC |
+--------------------------+
| group1    10 5.000 1.200 |
| group2    12 3.000 4.500 |
| group3    14 1.200 2.300 |
+--------------------------+
```

**Then you just do `df.heatmap.hvplot()` with hvplot >= 0.5:**

```
import pandas as pd
import holoviews as hv
import hvplot.pandas
hv.extension('bokeh')

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'colA': [10, 12, 14],
    'colB': [5, 3.0, 1.2],
    'colC': [1.2, 4.5, 2.3]},
    index=['group1', 'group2', 'group3'],
)

df.hvplot.heatmap()
```

**If you would like to add data labels to the heatmap you can do:**

```
heatmap = df.hvplot.heatmap()

heatmap * hv.Labels(heatmap)
```

**2) However when your data is like this where groups are just another column and not the index:**

```
+------------------------------+
|      group colA  colB  colC  |
+------------------------------+
| 1   group1    10 5.000 1.200 |
| 2   group2    12 3.000 4.500 |
| 3   group3    14 1.200 2.300 |
+------------------------------+
```

**Then you could either set your group as your index with `df.set_index('group')` (and apply solution 1), or [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) your data into a long format:**

```
df_melt = df.melt(id_vars='group')
```

After melting your data looks like this:

```
+---+--------+----------+--------+
|   | group  | variable | value  |
+---+--------+----------+--------+
| 0 | group1 | colA     | 10.000 |
| 1 | group2 | colA     | 12.000 |
| 2 | group3 | colA     | 14.000 |
| 3 | group1 | colB     | 5.000  |
| 4 | group2 | colB     | 3.000  |
+---+--------+----------+--------+
```

**This melted data is in the format where you can use the x and y and C keywords**:

```
df_melt.hvplot.heatmap(x='group', y='variable', C='value')
```

Or you can **use that melted (long) data to create the heatmap in HoloViews**:

```
hv.HeatMap(df_melt, kdims=['group', 'variable'], vdims=['value'])
```

**The advantage of melted data is that you can now also easily add data labels to your heatmap:**

```
heatmap = df_melt.hvplot.heatmap(x='group', y='variable', C='value')
labels = hv.Labels(data=df_melt, kdims=['group', 'variable'], vdims=['value'])

heatmap * labels
```

**Another (even) easier way to add data labels / values to your heatmap is like this:**

```
heatmap = df_melt.hvplot.heatmap(x='group', y='variable', C='value')
heatmap * hv.Labels(heatmap)
```

**Resulting plot:**

[image: nice heatmap with labels using hvplot or holoviews]

More info on heatmaps in hvplot:
 https://hvplot.holoviz.org/reference/pandas/heatmap.html

More info on heatmaps in holoviews:
https://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/HeatMap.html

More info on (data) labels in holoviews:
https://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/Labels.html

Comment: Many thanks, I did not know that df.melt could be applied here, looking forward to try this. Great explanation!

Answer (score 1):

For what you want, you can do :

```
df.hvplot.heatmap(x='index', y='columns', colorbar=True)
```